# Flask FieldList can't change data

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to generate a dynamic list of student from database, using *FieldList* and *FormField*. The fields are being generated using the data from database, but if I try to change something from the front-end, the back-end receives only the starting data (e.g., for checkbox it only gets False)

form:

```
class Beneficiary_Migration_Entry_Form(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('')
    id = StringField('')
    school = SelectField('', validate_choice=False)
    student_class = SelectField('', validate_choice=False)
    migrate = BooleanField('')
class Beneficiary_Migration_Form(FlaskForm):
    entry_form_list = FieldList(FormField(Beneficiary_Migration_Entry_Form))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

route

```
@app.route('/migration/student/<school_year_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def student_migration_page(school_year_id):
    school_year_id = int(school_year_id)
    school_year = School_Year.query.filter(School_Year.id==school_year_id).first()
    entry_form_list = []
    school_list = Database_Manager.get_school_list(current_user)
    school_choices = get_school_list()
        
    entries = Student.query.filter(Student.user_id==current_user.id).all()
    for entry in entries:
        form = Beneficiary_Migration_Entry_Form(
            name=entry.name,
            id=entry.id,
        )
        id_str = str(entry.id)
        form.name.name = 'name-' + id_str
        form.school.name = 'school-' + id_str
        form.migrate.name = 'migrate-' + id_str
        form.student_class.name = 'student_class-' + id_str
        form.id.name = 'id-' + id_str
        form.school.choices = school_choices
        form.student_class.choices = [('','')]
        entry_form_list.append(form)
    
    migration_form = Beneficiary_Migration_Form()
    migration_form.entry_form_list = entry_form_list
    school_map = Database_Manager.get_schools_map(current_user)

    if migration_form.submit.data:
        for form in migration_form.entry_form_list:
            print(form.migrate.data)
        return redirect(url_for('migration_page', school_year_id=school_year_id))
    return render_template('migration-elev.html', school_map=school_map,school_year=school_year, migration_form=migration_form)
```

Front-end:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ migration_form.hidden_tag() }}
    <table class="table table-striped table-dark" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nume</th>
            <th scope="col">Scoala</th>
            <th scope="col">Clasa/ Grupa</th>
            <th scope="col">Transfer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for form in migration_form.entry_form_list %}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <tr>
                    <td>{{form.id.value}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.school}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.student_class}}</td>
                    <td>{{form.migrate}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>{{ migration_form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary") }}</p>
</form>
```

At first it only got the data from the first entry from the FieldList, but I've found that I need to put unique names to work.

I've tried to use validate_on_submit but I get *AttributeError: 'Beneficiary_Migration_Form' object has no attribute 'copy'*.

I've also tried to use dictionaries and named tuples to load data, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified name to entry_name, since name is a reserved word.
To load data I've used append_data, where I've made a dictionary with data from db.